# Will my app remove from google play on May 05 if I target SDK 29 and use requestLegacyExternalStorage = true?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I recieved an warning message which says,

We've detected that your app contains the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag in the manifest file of 1 or more of your app bundles or APKs.

I am targeting android 10 and use `requestLegacyExternalStorage = true` ,

1. Will my app be removed from google play on May 5 th?
2. Do I need to remove `requestLegacyExternalStorage` flag from manifest before May 5?
3. Do I need to Update to target SDK to 30
4. Is there any other changes need if I use target sdk 29 and `requestLegacyExternalStorage = true`?

Answer (score 1):

I've written to Google and have got the following unswer:

```
Thank you for contacting Google Play Developer Support!

You are notified because your app supports devices running Android 11+. 

Please note that the targetSdkVersion fields means that your app works best on that level of API. It doesn't mean that the App will only run from that version and below. For more information, please refer to this developer documentation page.

To resolve this issue, please review the solutions given in the policy update email.

I hope this clarifies your concern. If you have any other questions about using the Play Console, please let me know.
```

So, As I understood we should add **maxSdkVersion=29** to not support Android 11+, and Google will not remove our apps

Comment: Do you use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: What is your current target SDK level?

Comment: No, I don't use  MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
My target SDK level is 29.
So, I was confused, because if I don't use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  and targetSDK=29 why I should do extra things for that

Answer (score 0):

> Apps that run on Android 11 but target Android 10 (API level 29) can still request the requestLegacyExternalStorage attribute. This flag allows apps to temporarily opt out of the changes associated with scoped storage, such as granting access to different directories and different types of media files. After you update your app to target Android 11, the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#scoped-storage